# Can't delete the folder created in My Documents with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I have tried to use the program described here [Problems in deleting a Folder during the uninstalation with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722747/problems-in-deleting-a-folder-durring-the-uninstalation-with-inno-setup)

after the answers were posted but for some unknown reason to me that code part isn't doing anything. May be related to windows version or if it's on 32 or 64 bit?

Here's the code used by me:

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged (CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
mres : integer;
begin
 case CurUninstallStep of
 usPostUninstall:
 begin
mres := MsgBox('Do you want to delete saved games?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2)
 if mres = IDYES then
   DelTree('ExpandConstant({userdocs}\SpellForce2)', True, True, True);
    end;  
  end;
end;
```

Any idea that could be useful to me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete a folder named **'ExpandConstant({userdocs}\SpellForce2)'** (literally), just remove the ' character to the ExpandConstant call (it is a call to a sub-routine).

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged (CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  mres : integer;
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
        mres := MsgBox('Do you want to delete saved games?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2)
        if mres = IDYES then
          DelTree(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\SpellForce2'), True, True, True);
      end;  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Kraemer Welcome to StackOverflow, if this answer works for you, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do

```
DelTree('ExpandConstant({userdocs}\SpellForce2)', True, True, True);
```

Of course, this should read

```
DelTree(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\SpellForce2'), True, True, True);
```